# How to use Streams for parallelism in Java

Tags: java, list, parallel-processing, java-stream, freemarker

I'm using a .ftl template to generate a custom report using Java, where I'll be using concept of list, but if I execute my tc parallel, those list will clash. So how do I achieve parallelism to generate the report using same template.ftl?

Main Class is below

```
public class Report {

    public static final List<ModuleDetails> testresultssummary = new ArrayList<ModuleDetails>();
    public static final List<TestCasesDetails> testresultsdetails = new ArrayList<TestCasesDetails>();
    public static final List<TestStepsDetails> teststepsdetails = new ArrayList<TestStepsDetails>();

    public static Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    static String MachineNumber = "";

    public static void AddModuleDetails(String moduleName, int passCount, int failCount, int notRunCount) {

        testresultssummary.add(new ModuleDetails(moduleName, Integer.toString(passCount), Integer.toString(failCount),
                Integer.toString(notRunCount)));
    }

    public static void UpdateModuleDetails(String moduleName, int passCount, int failCount, int notRunCount) {

        testresultssummary.set(testresultssummary.size() - 1, new ModuleDetails(moduleName, Integer.toString(passCount),
                Integer.toString(failCount), Integer.toString(notRunCount)));
    }

    public static void addTestCase(String moduleName, String testCaseName, String scenario, String status,
            String startTime, String endTime, String totalTime, String Exception, String testCaseID) {

        testresultsdetails.add(new TestCasesDetails(moduleName, testCaseName, scenario, status, startTime, endTime,
                totalTime, Exception, testCaseID));

    }

    public static void updateLastTestCase(String moduleName, String testCaseName, String scenario, String status,
            String startTime, String endTime, String totalTime, String Exception, String testCaseID) {

        testresultsdetails.set(testresultsdetails.size() - 1, new TestCasesDetails(moduleName, testCaseName, scenario,
                status, startTime, endTime, totalTime, Exception, testCaseID));
    }

    public static void addTestSteps(String testCase, String description, String expected, int Step_Num) {

        teststepsdetails.add(new TestStepsDetails(testCase, "Step " + Step_Num, description, expected, "Not Run"));
    }

    public static void AddResult(String testCase, String description, String expected, String Acutal, int Step_Num) {

        teststepsdetails.set(teststepsdetails.size() - 1,
                new TestStepsDetails(testCase, "Step " + Step_Num, description, expected, Acutal));

    }

    public static void TestExecutionSummary(String buildNumber, String machineNumber, String startTime, String endTime,
            String totalTime, String screenShotPath) {
        MachineNumber = machineNumber;
        data.put("buildNumber", buildNumber);
        data.put("machineNumber", machineNumber);
        data.put("startTime", startTime);
        data.put("endTime", endTime);
        data.put("totalTimeTaken", totalTime);
        data.put("screenShotPath", screenShotPath);
    }

    public static void writeToHTML() throws TemplateException {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        try {
            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("FrameworkLibrary/Reporting/template.ftl");
            data.put("testresultssummary", testresultssummary);
            data.put("testresultsdetails", testresultsdetails);
            data.put("teststepsdetails", teststepsdetails);
            String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
            Writer file = new FileWriter(new File("FrameworkLibrary/Reporting/Report/" + MachineNumber + ".html"));
            template.process(data, file);
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've got shared, mutable state.  You have to synchronize it if you intend to process in parallel.

Comment: It's wrong.  You understand why shared, mutable state and parallel processing don't mix, right?

Comment: Could you please provide me the exact solution

Comment: If it's just a matter of a shared template, perhaps you could give each process its own copy rather than trying to share the same one.

Comment: Why's "using same template.ftl" relevant here? When's the template ran at all? It's quite difficult to follow what results do you expect here.

Comment: What's the use of having multiple template .. Suppose if I have to run 10 test cases parallely , do I need 10 templates ?

Comment: There is no stream use in the posted code and it’s not clear what you are referring to, when you say “if I execute my tc parallel”

Comment: thats what my question is , how will i use streams instead of list in the above code .so it can work if more than 1 thread is running parallely